# How to append lots of variables to one variable with a simple command

Tags: bash, variables, awk, sed, sh

I want to stick all the variables into one variable

```
A=('blah')
AA=('blah2')
AAA=('blah3')
AAB=('blah4')
AAC=('blah5')
#^^lets pretend theres 100 more of these ^^
#Variable composition
#after AAA, is AAB then AAC then AAD etc etc, does that 100 times
```

I want them all placed into this MASTER variable

```
#MASTER=${A}${AA}${AAA} (<-- insert AAB, AAC and 100 more variables here)
```

I obviously don't want to type 100 variables in this expression because there's probably an easier way to do this. Plus I'm gonna be doing more of these therefore I need it automated.

I'm relatively new to sed, awk, is there a way to append those 100 variables into the master variable?

For this specific purpose I DO NOT want an array.

Comment: What you need is an Array. Have you even heard of it?

Comment: Which are the name patter of those variables? Can you tell us more about where those 100 come from?

Comment: Added some edits to add more clarification my bad.

Comment: Unless all your names are similar, you aren't going to have much choice but to type them all. You might try `for x in ${!A*}; do MASTER+="${!x}"; done`, but that assumes that `A*` matches exactly the set of variable names you want to concatenate. You can also use multiple patterns: `for x in ${!A*} ${!B*}; do`, for example.

Comment: By the way, `A=('blah')` defines an array with one element. Do you really want the parentheses there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *simple* one-liner, quite straightforward, though more expensive:

```
master=$(set | grep -E '^(A|AA|A[A-D][A-D])=' | sort | cut -f2- -d= | tr -d '\n')
```

- `set` lists all the variables in `var=name` format
- `grep` filters out the variables we need
- `sort` puts them in the right order (probably optional since `set` gives a sorted output)
- `cut` extracts the values, removing the variable names
- `tr` removes the newlines

---

Let's test it.

```
A=1
AA=2
AAA=3
AAB=4
AAC=5
AAD=6
AAAA=99 # just to make sure we don't pick this one up
master=$(set | grep -E '^(A|AA|A[A-D][A-D])=' | sort | cut -f2- -d= | tr -d '\n')
echo "$master"
```

Output:

```
123456
```

Answer (score 2):

With my best guess, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

A=('blah')
AA=('blah2')
AAA=('blah3')
AAB=('blah4')
AAC=('blah5')
# to be continued ..

for varname in A AA A{A..D}{A..Z}; do
    value=${!varname}
    if [ -n "$value" ]; then
        MASTER+=$value
    fi
done

echo $MASTER
```

which yields:

```
blahblah2blah3blah4blah5...
```

Although I'm not sure whether this is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z} | tr ' ' '\n' | head -n 100 | tail -n 3
adt
adu
adv
```

tells us, that it would go from AAA to ADV to reach 100, or for ADY for 103.

```
echo A{A..D}{A..Z} | sed 's/ /}${/g'
AAA}${AAB}${AAC}${AAD}${AAE}${AAF}${AAG}${AAH}${AAI}${AAJ}${AAK}${AAL}${AAM}${AAN}${AAO}${AAP}${AAQ}${AAR}${AAS}${AAT}${AAU}${AAV}${AAW}${AAX}${AAY}${AAZ}${ABA}${ABB}${ABC}${ABD}${ABE}${ABF}${ABG}${ABH}${ABI}${ABJ}${ABK}${ABL}${ABM}${ABN}${ABO}${ABP}${ABQ}${ABR}${ABS}${ABT}${ABU}${ABV}${ABW}${ABX}${ABY}${ABZ}${ACA}${ACB}${ACC}${ACD}${ACE}${ACF}${ACG}${ACH}${ACI}${ACJ}${ACK}${ACL}${ACM}${ACN}${ACO}${ACP}${ACQ}${ACR}${ACS}${ACT}${ACU}${ACV}${ACW}${ACX}${ACY}${ACZ}${ADA}${ADB}${ADC}${ADD}${ADE}${ADF}${ADG}${ADH}${ADI}${ADJ}${ADK}${ADL}${ADM}${ADN}${ADO}${ADP}${ADQ}${ADR}${ADS}${ADT}${ADU}${ADV}${ADW}${ADX}${ADY}${ADZ
```

The final cosmetics is easily made by hand.

Comment: I think the OP wants the *values* of the variables, not just their names.

Comment: @chepner: I don't think so.

Comment: `#MASTER=${A}${AA}${AAA}`, not `MASTER=AAAAAA`.

Comment: @chepner: I'm sorry, I don't get your point and I don't think you got mine. My impression is, that he doesn't want to type 100 variables, but want's to generate them. I might be wrong, but I don't even produce AAAAAA.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner using a `for loop`:

```
for n in A AA A{A..D}{A..Z}; do str+="${!n}"; done; echo ${str}
```

**Output**:

```
blahblah2blah3blah4blah5
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the input file `inputfile.txt`  with *arbitrary* variable names and values:

```
name="Joe"
last="Doe"
A="blah"
AA="blah2
```

then do:

```
master=$(eval echo $(grep -o "^[^=]\+" inputfile.txt | sed 's/^/\$/;:a;N;$!ba;s/\n/$/g'))
```

This will concatenate the values of all variables in `inputfile.txt` into `master` variable. So you will have:

```
>echo $master
JoeDoeblahblah2
```