# Bash echoing variable names, not values

Tags: bash, echo

I was trying to answer this question earlier on: [How to append lots of variables to one variable with a simple command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889355/how-to-append-lots-of-variables-to-one-variable-with-a-simple-command/)

I have one file (`inputfile.txt`) where some variables are initialize, for example:

```
name="Joe"
last="Doe"
...                        # Many more variables defined here
city="Los Angeles"
```

This file can be several lines long and the variable names are arbitrary. Now I want to echo all the variables in the input file by doing:

```
echo "$(grep -o "^[^=]\+" inputfile.txt | sed 's/^/\$/;:a;N;$!ba;s/\n/$/g')"
```

but this prints the variable names, so the output is:

```
$name$lastname...$city
```

My question is: Why is `echo` printing variable names and not their values? I'm aware that using single quotes will print the variable names (like `echo '${var}${var2}'` will print `${var}${var2}`). But in my case I have double quotes (`echo "${var1}${var2}"`) so why aren't the variable values being displayed?

Comment: You could use eval on the echo statement so that it produces the result you want - then you can echo that result.

Comment: Awesome, using eval worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using grep to parse inputfile.txt and in sed you are adding $ as a result you have string build from combination of $ and variable name which is not variable itself.